# Is there a way to merge two array of objects with same keys, summing up the other property's value?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to merge two arrays and sum the values having the same keys. Is it possible to do so?

```
public struct BassoValues
{
    public int BassoId { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public BassoValues(int bassoId, decimal amount)
    {
        BassoId = bassoId;
        Amount = amount;
    }
}

var arrayOne = new BassoValues[4]

arrayOne[0] = new BassoValues() { BassoId = 1, Amount = 1};
arrayOne[1] = new BassoValues() { BassoId = 2, Amount = 10};
arrayOne[2] = new BassoValues() { BassoId = 3, Amount = 20};
arrayOne[3] = new BassoValues() { BassoId = 4, Amount = 30};

var arrayTwo = new BassoValues[4]

arrayTwo[0] = new BassoValues() { BassoId = 1, Amount = 1};
arrayTwo[1] = new BassoValues() { BassoId = 2, Amount = 10};
arrayTwo[2] = new BassoValues() { BassoId = 3, Amount = 20};
arrayTwo[3] = new BassoValues() { BassoId = 4, Amount = 30};
```

I want to achieve the following result.

```
var arrayFinal = new BassoValues[4]

arrayFinal[0] = new BassoValues() { BassoId = 1, Amount = 2};
arrayFinal[1] = new BassoValues() { BassoId = 2, Amount = 20};
arrayFinal[2] = new BassoValues() { BassoId = 3, Amount = 40};
arrayFinal[3] = new BassoValues() { BassoId = 4, Amount = 60};
```

This is how I am trying to achieve the result:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOne.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayTwo.Length; j++)
        {
            if (arrayOne[0].BassoId == arrayTwo[0].BassoId)
            {
                var bassoId = arrayOne[0].BassoId;
                var sum = arrayOne[0].Amount + arrayTwo[0].Amount;
                arrayFinal[0] = new BassoValues() { bassoId, sum};
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what are the edge cases here ? can an array contain multiple items with the same ID?

Comment: You may also want to read up on the array initializer syntax (`var arrayOne = new [] { new BassoValues{BassoId =1, Amount =1}, … };`).  It's easier to type, easier to read and less error prone.

Comment: @MongZhu, no the array cannot contain items with same id, it has a fixed size of 4. I only need to sum the values for those objects having the same id.

Comment: ok, then my solution should suffice. But I guess I will post the other option still :)

Comment: Can do some ids be only in one array?

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions, as I am blocked.

The ids will always be the same for both arrays.

Comment: "The ids will always be the same for both arrays" But then it sounds like the Id's are superfluous in this case. Or can the order differ?

Comment: The best way of saying thank you on stackoverflow.com is to mark the answer that helped you as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

It'll work in cases when some ids aren't contained in both arrays and if ids can repeat inside one array as well.

```
 var result = arrayOne.Concat(arrayTwo).GroupBy(x => x.BassoId)
                         .Select(x => new BassoValues(x.Key, x.Sum(y => y.Amount)))
                         .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to join the arrays using the Id:

```
var sumarray = (from a1 in arrayOne
join a2 in arrayTwo on a1.BassoId equals a2.BassoId
select new BassoValues {BassoId = a1.BassoId, Amount = a1.Amount + a2.Amount}).ToArray();
```

EDIT: In case that each array can contain multiple entries with the same ID and you want to sum them up then the linq-join solution will not suffice anymore. You could group by the id and calculate the sums per id in a loop:

```
List<BassoValues> Result = new List<BassoValues>();

foreach (var element in arrayOne.GroupBy(x => x.BassoId))
{
    BassoValues temp = new BassoValues {BassoId = element.Key};
    temp.Amount = arrayTwo.Where(x => x.BassoId == temp.BassoId).Sum(x => x.Amount) + element.Sum(x => x.Amount);           
    Result.Add(temp);
}
```

Comment: Guess @marrs wants to get 'full outer join'

Comment: @Kamushek I guess he needs to specify that. In this case the solution would be much more complicated

Comment: `var arr = arrayOne.Concat(arrayTwo);
            var result = arr.GroupBy(x => x.BassoId).Select(x => new BassoValues(x.Key, x.Sum(y => y.Amount))).ToArray();` Wierd flex, but ok :D

Comment: @Kamushek I thought about a concat option but then decided to make it with a loop. But you can/should post this version of yours as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You say your arrays' sizes are fixed to 4.

```
var arrayFinal = new BassoValues[4]; // create final array
// loop each array
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int amount = arrayOne[i].Amount + arrayTwo[i].Amount;
    arrayFinal[i] = new BassoValues() { BassoId = (i+1), Amount = amount };
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain _how_ it solves the problem without introducing others and _why_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: editing was the way, but this edit seems insufficient. stop-cran comment still stands

Comment: Everything seems obvious to me. I couldn't find any vague line.